# Building Android project on remote server from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

I'm currently at a stage where I need to frequently rebuild my Android application in release mode (and using Proguard). My application is pretty complex, so each build in release mode from Eclipse takes around ~75 seconds, which is a huge waste of time when I'm doing this dozens of times.

I have an Amazon AWS account and I can launch an instance with high CPU resources. Is there a script/plugin/built-in feature in Eclipse that would allow me to automatically send the code to the server to be built and then retrieve the finished APK?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup Jenkins and trigger build from there. Combined with crashlytics you have all the power in the world at the finger of your hands.